# How can I "disable" a radio button, without removing the text value, and whether it's checked or not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to display the current value of a radio button, whether it's checked or not, but I want to prevent a user from changing the value.  I also want to keep the text value.  When I set the Enable property to "false", it lightened the button so you can't tell that it's checked, and it also removed the text that I had set for the (radio) button.  Am I mission something.

Comment: At the end I should have said "Am I missing something".  I doing it in C# for a Windows Form application.  Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, because from my memory (and it has been a long time, I admit), I'm sure setting enabled to false used to just dim everything. It really should NOT remove the label!

Comment: Yeah, the removing of text shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Maybe you have a black background, so you don't see the text anymore. On a white-ish background both the button and the Text can be seen much better when the control is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AutoCheck` property:

```
myRadioButton.AutoCheck = false; // disabled
myRadioButton.AutoCheck = true;  // enabled
```

Comment: I know it says to avoid comments like "Thanks", but thank you for responding.  That did it.